# How should I change TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS in Django?

Tags: python, django, social-networking

I'm trying to use the `Django Social Auth` [application](https://github.com/omab/django-social-auth) to handle logins to my site from a variety of social media sites.

When working through the example code [here](https://github.com/omab/django-social-auth/blob/master/example/example/settings.py), the example uses the following settings for `TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS`:

```
TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS = (    
    'django.core.context_processors.debug',
    'django.core.context_processors.i18n',
    'django.core.context_processors.media',
    'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
    'social_auth.context_processors.social_auth_by_type_backends',
    'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
)
```

However, if I use these settings my static media url is ignored (css/js/images are not available), and I think it is overwriting some other context settings. How can I check if there are more context settings that I should be including?

Comment: Incidentally, I am using `Django Social Auth` as it seems to be the most flexible and best documented of applications of this type. I'm open to using another package if that is strongly recommended.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to add `django.core.context_processors.static` to your list of context processors.

Then maybe have a quick read through the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/howto/static-files/) on serving static files - The process varies depending on your setup.

It's difficult to say what else you might need in there, I think you've got everything that django drops in there as default (when you run `python django-admin.py startapp`). Glancing at one of the current projects I'm working on, I've got `django.core.context_processors.request` for passing the request object into the template and one custom context_processor, but obviously what you add is subject to your specific requirements.

Answer (score 1):

Have you set your `STATICFILES_DIRS`? Also, you should add the `django.core.context_processors.static` to your `TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS` and address your static files using the [STATIC_URL](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/api/#django-core-context-processors-static).

Also the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/static-files/) on static files are generally a good read.